# MySQL Want to SUM and Minus from two SQL statements

Tags: mysql

I want to SUM the first Statement(A) and Second Statement(B) Then I want to get the result of A-B. After that I get the output GROUP BY `who`

```
SELECT `who`, mpoints-spoints AS netpoints 
FROM
(
SELECT `who`,`points`, SUM(points) AS mpoints FROM `game` WHERE (`datetime` BETWEEN '2015-12-1' AND '2015-12-31') AND (`cal`='1') AND (`result`='1' OR `result`='2') GROUP BY `who`
) t1,
(
SELECT `who`,`points`, SUM(points) AS spoints FROM `game` WHERE (`datetime` BETWEEN '2015-12-1' AND '2015-12-31') AND (`cal`='1') AND (`result`='3' OR `result`='4') GROUP BY `who`
) t2
ORDER BY netpoints DESC
GROUP BY `who`
```

I want the output like

```
whlie($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
No.    Who.           Points
$i++   $rs['who']        $rs['netpoints']
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the results you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query could look like the following, but I have not tested it.

```
SELECT `who`, mpoints-spoints AS netpoints 
FROM
(
SELECT `who`,`points`, SUM(points) AS mpoints, 0 as spoints FROM `game` WHERE (`datetime` BETWEEN '2015-12-1' AND '2015-12-31') AND (`cal`='1') AND (`result`='1' OR `result`='2') GROUP BY `who`
UNION ALL
SELECT `who`,`points`, 0 as mpoints, SUM(points) AS spoints FROM `game` WHERE (`datetime` BETWEEN '2015-12-1' AND '2015-12-31') AND (`cal`='1') AND (`result`='3' OR `result`='4') GROUP BY `who`
) A
GROUP BY `who`
ORDER BY netpoints;
```